# How to start AWS RDS on a different port than the default port of 3306 in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, admin, aws-cli

**How to start AWS RDS on a different port than the default port of 3306 in ubuntu**

1. I don't no how to start with the new port rather than the default.

so if anyone knows the steps kindly help me so that it will be useful for me.

Comment: "In Ubuntu" is not a logical part of this question, since RDS is a managed service, and cannot be said to run "in" Ubuntu or any other operating system in any meaningful way.   RDS instances certainly run on some kind of operating system, of course, but which OS that might be is not relevant to RDS customers.

Answer (score 5):

When you create a RDS instance via the console, you can specify a different Database Port (on step 4): 
[image: RDS database options]

If you are using the AWS CLI, you can also specify a different port with the option `--port`. See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/create-db-instance.html

You can also specify a different port when creating the RDS instance using CloudFormation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html

Comment: Aussourd thanks you so much for giving an idea.. I don't no anything about AWS and i have no idea... so can u help me out from the first step. So that it will be very helpful for me to learn about AWS

Comment: @klee Do you have access to the console (web interface)? Where is your data: do you have a RDS snapshot or do you have a DB dump?

Comment: Is it possible to change after the instance has been created?

Comment: @ZhouHao Yes, it's possible

Answer (score 2):

***True to 2020:***

[image: RDS]

Will be useful for friends looking for answers in 2020

Comment: This is still true in Aug 2023, however it's not clear from the screenshot which of the "additional configuration" sections need to be expanded (many of the sections have a such a dropdown). Currently, the option is found by expanding the "Additional configuration" in the "Connectivity" section.